# take screenshot without one specific program window

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot

I need to take a regular screenshot but i need for a way to disregard an open application. In the screenshot must appear the regular background as if the application/window wasn't open.

In other words, i need one screenshot without an window/aplication (which is presemnt) but appearing what is behind of this window/aplication, disregarding the window/ap.

For get screenshot i have the folowing code in QT/c++:

```
(...)
QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();

QPixmap qPImage = screen->grabWindow(0);

QImage qImg = qPImage.toImage();//convert to qImage

(...)
```

It is possible do what i need?

Regards 
Alex

Comment: maybe you can try minimizing the app, taking the screenshot and then maximizing it?

Answer (score 1):

May be not the perfect solution, but this is what I did in the exact same situation:

```
void MainWindow::onUpdateClicked()
{
    hide();
    QTimer::singleShot(45, this, SLOT(updateScreenshotPicture()));
}

void MainWindow::updateScreenshotPicture()
{
    screenshotBorders->setPic(QPixmap::grabWindow(QApplication::desktop()->winId()));
    show();
}
```